# SQLite update query - subquery with aliases doesn't work

Tags: sqlite, subquery, alias

I need to update a SQLite table.

The table looks like:

```
ID   | Address            | CallNumber   |  RefID
-----+--------------------+-------------------------------------------
ef78 | library            | 2002/13      | 100002
no56 | Lit                | 0189         | 100003
rs90 | temp               |              | 100003
```

For every column with Address = "Lit" there is a column Address = 'temp' with the same RefID.
Now I need to update each Address = "temp" with the value "CallNumber" from the column with the same RefID.

The updated table should look like:

```
ID   | Address            | CallNumber   |  RefID
-----+--------------------+-------------------------------------------
ef78 | library            | 2002/13      | 100002
no56 | Lit                | 0189         | 100003
rs90 | 0189               |              | 100003
```

I tried this:

```
UPDATE Location
SET address = foo.callnumber
FROM (select RefID, CallNumber FROM Location) foo
WHERE foo.RefID=Location.RefID AND Location.Address = 'temp';
```

But all I got is a syntax error near "from".

Any clue?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`UPDATE` commands [do not have a `FROM` clause](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html).

Use a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE Location
SET Address = (SELECT CallNumber
               FROM Location L2
               WHERE L2.RefID = Location.RefID
                 AND L2.Address = 'Lit')
WHERE Address = 'temp'
```

Comment: This works but what if I want to update multiple fields with and not to call the same inner quarry multiple times ?

Comment: @PiniCheyni Then you must decide whether avoiding multiple subqueries is more important than not solving your actual problem.