# Update value if columns in different tables match

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE CustomProperties (
      ID         INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
    , programID  INTEGER
    , Key        VARCHAR
)

CREATE TABLE XXXCustom (
      licID  INTEGER
    , propID INTEGER -- points to CustomProperties.ID
    , Value  VARCHAR
)
```

`CustomProperties` serves as a register of different types of custom properties which my programs can contain. `XXXCustom` stores the custom properties actually used by program XXX (another table stores properties shared by all programs).

Now, if I want to modify an object's custom property, I know both the `Key` and the `Value` I want to modify it to. However, I first need to "convert" the `Key` into the relevant `ID`, which I then use to locate the desired row in `XXXCustom`.

I tried

```
UPDATE XXXCustom
SET pp.Value = 'TEST'
FROM CustomProperties cp INNER JOIN XXXCustom pp
ON pp.propID = cp.ID AND pp.Key = 'test'
```

But this throws a syntax error, probably because [`UPDATE` doesn't have a `FROM` clause](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15499314/2175231), [nor can you use `JOIN` directly in an `UPDATE`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21775498/2175231). Fair enough.

So I tried

```
UPDATE (SELECT cp.Key, pp.Value
        FROM CustomProperties cp INNER JOIN FtoolCustom pp
        WHERE cp.ID = pp.propID)
SET pp.Value = 'TEST'
ON pp.Key = 'test'
```

But this also throws a syntax error, I believe because `UPDATE` doesn't work on subqueries, but [requires a qualified table name](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html).

So now I'm out of ideas. Do I have to do this manually in steps: first "convert" the `Key` to its ID and then use that ID to update `XXXCustom`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
UPDATE XXXCustom
SET value='myval'
WHERE licID=(SELECT id FROM CustomProperties WHERE key='mykey');
```